# Keep scrapyd running

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I have scrapy and scrapyd installed on a debian machine. I log in to this server using a ssh-tunnel. I then start scrapyd by going:
    scrapyd

Scrapyd starts up fine and I then open up another ssh-tunnel to the server and schedule my spider with:
curl localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=myspider

The spider runs nicely and everything is fine.

The problem is that scrapyd stops running when I quit the session where I started up scrapyd. This prevents me from using cron to schdedule spiders with scrapyd since scrapyd isn't running when the cronjob is launched.

My simple question is: How do I keep scrapyd running so that it doesn't shut down when I quit the ssh session.

Comment: Can scrapyd be added a service and then be scheduled on bootup using `ntsysv`?

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47067997/4094231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it in a screen session:

```
$ screen
$ scrapyd

# hit ctrl-a, then d to detach from that screen

$ screen -r # to re-attach to your scrapyd process
```

Comment: scrapyd is designed to run as a daemon. Screen is not appropriate solution.

Comment: I agree here with @FredericBazin. If scrapyd shuts down or crashes it will not restart. This "hack" is ok for the short term, but I would use this method in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider launching scrapyd with [supervisor](http://supervisord.org).

And there is a good .conf script available as a gist here:
https://github.com/JallyHe/scrapyd/blob/master/supervisord.conf

Answer (score 0):

How about  ?
    $ sudo service scrapyd start